# The tags [konva] and [konvajs] should be synonymous

Tags: feature-request, tags, synonym-request

The tags [konva](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/konva) and [konvajs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/konvajs) should be synonymous.

I don't have any answer score for them, so I can't suggest a synonym myself.